# Can't instantiate a COM object written in C# from VBA (VB6 ok)

Tags: c#, .net, vba, com, com-interop

Using VS 2008, here is my COM object

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestCom
{    
    [Guid("9E5E5FB2-219D-4ee7-AB27-E4DBED8E123E")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
    [ProgId("Test9.COMINT")]
    public class TestComClass  
    { 
        public void Init(string userid, string password)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0}/{1}", userid, password));
        }       
    }
}
```

If I build this and register it on a production machine as follows

```
REGASM /CODEBASE TESTCOM.DLL
```

From a simple VB6 app this works fine

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
  Dim o As Object
  Set o = CreateObject("Test9.COMINT")
  o.Init "A", "B" 
End Sub
```

This exact same code called from VBA in Excel gives

> "automation error" (0x80131700)

Everything works fine on a development machine, just not on a production machine with just .NET and MS Office installed.

### Update

I think this is something to do with the .NET framework not being initialized properly, when running under Excel. If I use Filemon I can see it skip around looking for MSCORWKS.DLL. When I call the same object from VBScript, it finds MSCorwks.dll fine.

When I called `CorBindToCurrentRunTime` from VBA to try to forcibly load the CLR, interestingly I get the exact same `HRESULT (0x80131700)` as when I do `CreateObject()` in VBA.

Therefore I think it is a framework initialization issue.

Comment: I just went through and tried to reproduce this and it works fine on my machine as well. Wish I could help more

Comment: because your machine has Visual Studio etc., I bet. I will definitely post on here when I have a solution. Thank you all for your time.

Comment: @rc1: Great... Sysinternals saves the day for another one! :)

Answer (score 14):

I'm going to answer my own question, hopefully to spare others the hours of tedious drudgery I have just endured.

If you get this, it **is** because the .NET based COM assembly can't find the .NET framework

The solution is simple. Create a file containing the following

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
   <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Call it "Excel.Exe.Config" and place it in the same directory as "EXCEL.EXE"

Problem solved!

Comment: nice would never have guessed

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this, *especially* for a real deployed app (ie, please don't go deploying Excel.exe.config files on user machines!). Excel is a shared app host that you don't really "own"- this config file changes the way all managed code works in Excel. This will break any managed Excel add-in that doesn't use CLR 2.0. You should be able to get the same effect with correct registration (check the CLR version under your object's CLSID registry entry) and/or a CLR-loading shim.

Answer (score 2):

installing the follow fix will resolve this issue
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=1b0bfb35-c252-43cc-8a2a-6a64d6ac4670&displaylang=en

Answer (score 1):

RC1, I tested this with your code from VBScript and from within Office 2007's Excel, everything works fine.

Since your able to create the COM object from within a VB6 form we should assume that your .net framework is ok. Can you rule out issues with VBA? Can you create a .vbs file and put this in it:

```
Dim o As Object  
Set o = CreateObject("Test9.COMINT")  
o.Init "A", "B"
```

Save the file and double click it. If you get an error, then I would think there is an issue with it being registered, if you don't get an error, then I would look at Office and VBA and see if something is missing or not installed properly.

Another option is to add a reference to COM object and use early binding? I think you might need to export a typelibrary first, but you should be able to add a reference and simple new the object up.

Comment: Works fine from VBScript too (need to lose the 'as object')

I just created a VB6 COM DLL wrapper around the C# com object. Excel can instantiate that DLL fine, and call its own methods, but when that VB6 DLL in turn calls methods in the C# object, I get "automation error" again.

Comment: ... so it seems the problem's related to the fact Excel's running

Answer (score 0):

This works for me from VBA...  I tried it using Word & Excel 2003 (SP3).

I'm not sure what you mean by "production" machine.  Because this is a "client" application and must be executed on the client using Excel.

If you're automating Excel on the server and triggering this "interop" through a VBA call, you're asking for trouble :)

Assuming that by production, you mean the client machine where user will be using the Excel template / doc, these are the following pointers:

1. Make sure you have the appropriate .Net framework
2. That you have latest service packs for Office
3. Try ascertain if this is a rights issue.

If you're feeling adventuristic, you could use a process explorer [from Microsoft sysinternals site] to see what're the DLLs loaded and where exactly are you getting the error and compare it to the list on your dev box.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Vyas. Yes by production machine I just mean an end user machine with Office and .NET, but no Visual Studio etc. Does it work for you on a similar machine? Are you in a position to share some code? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

rc1 is correct in that this **is** a .net error, thrown when Office can't decide which version of the Framework to use. However, Office isn't throwing a wobbly simply because it's spoilt for choice. There is a bug in how Office 2003 interacts with .net 2.0.

Installing the fix from Microsoft ([KB908002](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/908002/en-us)) is a more flexible way of solving the problem than by forcing Excel to run in a particular version of .net.

See also: http://www.biopdf.com/guide/trouble_shoot_microsoft_office_2003.php