# linking c# gui project and library dll project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, user-interface

This snippet is a helloworld-like example illustrating the framework goal I am trying to achieve. The goal of this project is to control the GUI from a seperate piece of code in C# or VBA, e.g. an automation routine that talks to equipment and other pieces of software. The GUI is there for the benefit of the user not using automation, but I also want to automate pieces of the GUI as if someone were there

I am trying to link a GUI and a COM dll together as stated above without much success.

Both projects work separately.

1. I have verified I can call the COM dll functions.
2. I have also verified the simple GUI works.
3. Now I would like to have functions inside the GUI that are callable from the COM dll.

I thought it was as easy as adding the other project and adding a reference, but I am doing something wrong. It's funny because the code completion makes it seem as I am very close, as you can see from the screenshots.

[image]

GUI Project:

```
namespace GUI_HELLOWORLD
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hello World.");
        }
        public void Button1_Click()
        {
            //For the sake of clicking through code - figure out correct method later
            MessageBox.Show("Hello World.");
        }
    }
 }
```

DLL project:

```
namespace GUI_COM_LIB
{
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisible(true)] //- may not be necessary in some cases?
    public class ZZ_GUI_HELLOWORLD_API_DEMO
    {
        public void SelHello()
        {
            GUI_HELLOWORLD.MainWindow.Button1_Click(); // ERROR!
        }
```

When adding a reference to the GUI into the COM_LIB dll project, I can see the GUI in the pop up menu, so it's seeing it's there! However when I type `GUI_HELLOWORLD.MainWindow.`, no public functions come up where I would expect to see Button1_Click()

[image]

Comment: I took a closer look at your screenshots, and are you sure you've got your references right?  Your Library is referencing your GUI project.  *Assuming* that you have already generated an assembly for your COM Component (it looks like you already have) you would add a reference to your GUI project and point that reference to the COM Assembly.

Comment: Regarding your final screenshot above, what Wes said seems to be correct.  You have not constructed a "MainWindow" in order to call a button click. "Button_Click" exists as a click handler inside your MainWindow class, but why are you trying to reference this handler from within your class library?  Perhaps if I understood your goal a little better, I'd be able to see a clear path to a solution. I wouldn't personally architect a solution in this manner, so I can't really help more without a bit more context. It looks a bit foreign to me.

Comment: I am absolutely sure I have my references right. I want to call elements of the GUI from another program. So I must reference the GUI project in that other program. What Wes said is getting at the root problem. His solution works for making a new window, but I want to access the window that is already open, not a newly created GUI. Have any ideas on a better architecture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[WCF named pipe minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7353670/wcf-named-pipe-minimal-example)

I found the solution in this thread. By using a channel system, an interface can be created and functions from the GUI can be piped over to a dll. The dll is then callable from C#, Excel VBA, or other .NET.

Answer (score 0):

It's never quite that simple with COM components.
Have you looked through this ancient tome?

[Calling COM Components from .NET Clients](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973800.aspx)

Specifically, have you run TLBIMP on your COM component?

**Edit**

Check out this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5022768/passing-objects-from-c-sharp-to-vba-using-com-interop)
[This Blog Post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2009/11/05/interop-between-vba-and-visual-studio-office-solutions-vsto.aspx)

Is your Client built as an Excel Add-In? (using Visual Studio Tools for Office)

Comment: any other methods for providing an excel vba API to a C# GUI?

Comment: Sure.  Is your C# GUI an Excel Add-In?

Comment: Hmm I may have to pursue this, it's not an add-in at the moment. My current problem is that I have a working GUI and I have a working C# COM library I can call from excel. I need pieces of the GUI to be callable excel as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need an instance of your window object:

```
public void SelHello()
{
    var myWindow = new GUI_HELLOWORLD.MainWindow();
    myWindow.Button1_Click();
}
```

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood. It appeared to be two .NET projects communicating between each other.

Comment: It looks like he's already generated the assembly from the COM Component, but after taking a second look at the screenshot, his reference is backwards

Comment: This works. It generates the popup that would happen if I clicked on the button1. However, this isn't quite what I want. I want to click the button in the GUI that is already open.