# Cannot call C# library exposed through COM in Excel VBA

Tags: c#, vba, com, interop

I have tried to create a very basic C# library and expose it through COM interface so that I can access it from VBA, but at runtime it throws an error "Class does not support Automation or does not support expected interface"

I have read all the online tutorials and done exactly as specified so am very confused why this is. My basic class is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace PDCCOMTest
{

    [ComVisible(true)]
    public interface IPDCCOMTest
    {
        string SubmitRequest(string requestXML);
    }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(IPDCCOMTest))]
    [ProgId("PDCCOMTest.PDCCOMTest")]
    public class PDCCOMTest : IPDCCOMTest
    {
        public string SubmitRequest(string requestXML)
        {
            return "hello world";
        }
    }
}
```

And in the project settings I have gone to Application -> Assembly Information -> Make assembly COM visible (Set to ON) and Build -> Register for COM interop (Set to ON)

I compile and build the solution, then load up Excel and set up a basic button macro sheet. In this, I go to References and under the list of COM objects, my new C# COM assembly appears and I check it. I am then able to discover the types with Intellisense and the SubmitRequest method is available from Intellisense so it is picking all that up fine. The VBA code is as follows

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim oObj As New PDCCOMTest.PDCCOMTest
    Dim text As String
    test = oObj.SubmitRequest("test")
End Sub
```

When I then run the sheet and click the button, it throws the error on the last line of the Sub above, ie the SubmitRequest() line

"Error 430 : Class does not support Automation or does not support expected interface"

Can anyone please suggest what I have overlooked and why this is happening?

Thanks,
James

Comment: Probably has nothing to do with it but you have `text` and `test` in your vba code.

Comment: Ah good spot. It hasn't fixed the error no, but thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Remove the ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None) attribute

Comment: You need a GUID for your interface and another one for your class

Comment: Ok looks like I've found the solution. 

In Excel.exe.config in the program files directory, there is a line

<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">

If I set this to false it works, so clearly some issue with .NET runtime versioning. Any idea why this might be and how I can fix it in my VS2010 project so that I can leave this option as "TRUE" and have it succeed?

Comment: Does your Excel.exe.config have a section that looks like this?:
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
</startup>

Comment: It does, and it had an entry for v4.0.30319 - and that framework exists on my machine, but when I use VS2010 to compile the DLL under framework 4.0 in the dropdown and try that, it doesnt work. If I add an entry to the excel.exe.config section you mentioned for suported framework 3.5 and compile the DLL under 3.5 - then it works. Cannot get it working with 4.0 for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works on my machine so your code is probably fine. If I were to hazard a guess, I would say that it looks like a .NET loading issue, i.e. Excel has loaded some other .NET add-ins and loaded the CLR v1 or such.

Take a look at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375457/cant-instantiate-a-com-object-written-in-c-sharp-from-vba-vb6-ok) - hope it helps.