# Custom C# DLL gives VBA 429 error

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2012, com, vba

I'm trying to figure out how to solve this. I tried many things that I saw on internet but with no success. I tried: to use regasm, compile target as x86, dumpbin dll /t:dll.tlb, change the version of Framework etc.

I have two machines (M1 and M2) both with windows 7 64 and VS2012. When I develop a COM in M1, it runs fine in VBA of M1. But it doesn't work for M2 (Error 429). Then, if I go to M2 and write a new COM, it works fine in VBA of M2, but not for M1.

It seems that VS2012 is performing a "hidden" registration step that I can't see. Does someone know how to find that?

Many thanks! Below is my "COM Hello World". I'm using Register for COM interop as well.

UPDATE:

If I run:

```
C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm TesteLib.dll /TesteLib.tlb
```

the 429 error disappears. But now, instead of error 429, I'm getting "error -2147024894 (80070002) Automation Error" in the same line.

I followed the solution from [Can't instantiate a COM object written in C# from VBA (VB6 ok)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375457/cant-instantiate-a-com-object-written-in-c-sharp-from-vba-vb6-ok) to create a Excel.Exe.Config inside EXCEL.exe folder and my program runs fine now. But I think that I can't perform this on client machines. Is there an alternative to that?

Also, it works ok in VB6 (without the need to perform the REGASM).

.net side

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TesteLib
{
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
    [Guid("c6b093c6-f568-4962-8955-795fc14f34bb")]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public interface ClassInt1
    {
        int sum(int a, int b);
    }

    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [Guid("19ff9b41-8652-4012-ac55-c1a1d8f18cbb")]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [ProgId("TesteLib.Class1")]
    public class Class1 : COMException, ClassInt1
    {
        public int sum(int a, int b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }
    }

}
```

VBA side

```
Sub t()
    Dim r As TesteLib.Class1
    Set r = New TesteLib.Class1 'Run-time error '429': ActiveX component can't create object
    MsgBox r.Sum(35, 51)
End Sub
```

Comment: registered with admin privileges? I know for sure on win 7 x64 and vs12 and a domained computer if I dont start the vs2012 as administrator the *.dll will not be registered. just a reminder really

Comment: I think I figured out. It was missing the parameter /codebase in regasm. Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: consider adding an answer to your question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now it's working!

I needed to register the DLL using the REGASM with the option /codebase

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm /codebase TesteLib.dll
```

When I include the option /codebase it generates a warning, but it works: RegAsm warning: *Registering an unsigned assembly with /codebase can cause your assembly to interfere with other applications that may be installed on the same computer. The /codebase switch is intended to be used only with signed assemblies. Please give your assembly a strong name and re-register it*.

Then, In VS2012 I marked the option Project Properties > Signing > Sign the assembly > New... and run REGASM. The warning faded out and everything seems to be fine now :)

Thanks!